# Why is "pipenv install" not installing any packages?

Tags: pipenv, pipenv-install

`pip freeze` shows all the packages, but when I `pipenv install` it is not installing any packages.

Here's what I'm getting when I do `pipenv install`:

```
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (0a15b8)...
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3):

I expect you are using pipenv virtual env as well for your project. I uninstalled all the packages from the env using: `pipenv uninstall --all` and then did `pipenv install` to install all the packages from pipfile and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with:

```bash
pipenv update
pipenv install
```